# azure acs authentication in winrt

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, windows-runtime, acs

I'm trying to authenticate users in a winrt metro app using Azure ACS.
I've set up a relying party in azure with a simple webtoken.

on windows 8 I've installed the azure toolkit. When I created a new project from the winrt cloud (notifications + acs) template and I fill in all necessary parameters I can run the app, I get the live ID login screen but when I enter my credentials I get a message saying "We can't load that page".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: when I set a breakpoint in my code it appears that the OnLogin event never fires

Answer (score 0):

With "I fill in all necessary parameters" I'm assuming you mean the **Configuration.xml** file contains the necessary information to your ACS namespace etc...

Now, filling in this information and configuring ACS isn't enough to make the sample work. If you take a closer look at the **Configuration.xml** file, you'll see the following elements:

```
<!--Relying party return Url. The bouncer service url that will parse the token from ACS.-->
<ReturnUrl>https://127.0.0.1/bouncer</ReturnUrl>

<!--Authentication End Url. The bouncer service url used to validate if the authentication process is done.-->
<EndUrl>https://127.0.0.1/bouncer/end</EndUrl>
```

These are URLs from an Azure application you'll also need to run in order for the sample to work. In the toolkit you'll find the following directory:

**WATWindows.Setup.v1.2.4\Samples\Notifications.CSharp\Notifications.Backend**

To be able to run the sample application you'll need to start this backend application first.

And did you already run the **SetupSample.cmd** script in the **WATWindows.Setup.v1.2.4\Samples\Notifications.CSharp** directory?

Comment: backend application is running and I did run the setupsample script
I'm getting the same result on the sample as on a new application